# Recursive Binary Search Tree not printing data in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, recursion

I am currently learning java by writing my programs from C++ to Java.
I am trying to print the data using recursive binary search tree, but its not printing

Here is my code:

```
public class PersonRec {
    int bribe;
    PersonRec lchild;
    PersonRec rchild;   
}

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tree {
    private PersonRec root;

    public Tree()
    {
        root = null;
    }

    public void Add()
    {       
        int aBribe;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);  

        System.out.println("Enter person's contribution: ");
        aBribe = scan.nextInt();

        Insert(root, aBribe);       
    }

    public void Insert(PersonRec root, int aBribe)
    {
        if(root == null)
        {
            root = new PersonRec();
            root.rchild = null;
            root.lchild = null;

            root.bribe = aBribe;
        }       
        else if(aBribe < root.bribe)
        {
            Insert(root.lchild, aBribe);
        }
        else
        {
            Insert(root.rchild, aBribe);
        }
    }

    public void view()
    {               
        if(root == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Tree is empty" + "\n");
        }
        else
            DisplayTree(root);
    }

    public void DisplayTree(PersonRec root)
    {               
        if(root == null)
            return;

        DisplayTree(root.lchild);
        System.out.println(" " + root.bribe);
        System.out.println("\n");   
        DisplayTree(root.rchild);

    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {   
        Tree myList = new Tree();       
        int choice;     

        do
        {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("\nMenu\n");
            System.out.println("==============================\n\n");
            System.out.println("1. Add student to waiting list\n");
            System.out.println("2. View waiting list\n");
            System.out.println("3. Exit program \n_");
            System.out.println("Please enter choice: ");
            choice = scan.nextInt();

            switch(choice)
            {
                case 1: myList.Add();
                break;

                case 2: myList.view();
                break;          

            }           
        }
        while(choice != 3);         
    }   
}
```

When I type 1, i insert a bribe amount example: 23
when i type 2 again fro the menu its not being inserted in my tree it says, "tree is empty"

Thanks

Comment: how do you doo this `aBribe < root.bribe` ? does this even work.

Comment: is that statement wrong> aBribe < root.bribe?

Comment: Just a couple of thoughts to help you avoid a lot of frustration: first of all, use an IDE. Eclipse and Netbeans are the two most popular choices. IDEs can enforce stricter rules than the language does. You can for example configure it to flag up re-assignment to method parameters as warnings or errors. (This would've helped you here.) And you get a debugger with them.My other advice is to learn the Java [naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html), specifically that method names should always start with lowercase characters.

Comment: Im using Eclipse and aware of java naming conventions.  i dont know what you are talking about

Comment: I'm talking about methods called `Add()`, `DisplayTree()` instead of `add()` and `displayTree()`.

Comment: oh i see, it has been resolved thanks biziclop!

Comment: You're welcome and don't worry, switching from C++ to Java is a lot harder than it sounds, everyone bumps into a lot of problems on the way.

Comment: Side note: good programming practice is to not include input/output in your data structures directory.  Keep your data structures relatively dumb, and have only the methods you need to modify and traverse the data in a way that's independent of how it will be input or used.  If you want to add something to the tree, have a method somewhere else that reads the input and then calls Add(int bribe)  method.  Secondly, for the output, look into the Visitor pattern.

Answer (score 2):

In you Insert method, root is just a local variable inside the method.
And since at leaf level, null is passed, it has lost the connection with your myList.
You have to create instance for lchild before move on to Insert(root.lchild, aBribe).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class PersonRec {
    int bribe;
    String name;
    PersonRec lchild;
    PersonRec rchild;
}

public class Tree {
    private PersonRec root;

    public Tree() {
        root = null;
    }

    public void Add() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter person's name: ");
        String name = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Enter person's contribution: ");
        int aBribe = scan.nextInt();

        this.Add(name, aBribe);
    }

    public void Add(String name, int aBribe) {
        if (this.root == null) {
            root = this.createRecord(name, aBribe);
        } else {
            this.Insert(root, name, aBribe);
        }
    }

    private PersonRec createRecord(String name, int aBribe) {
        PersonRec rec = new PersonRec();
        rec.bribe = aBribe;
        rec.name = name;
        rec.rchild = null;
        rec.lchild = null;
        return rec;
    }

    private void Insert(PersonRec rec, String name, int aBribe) {
        if (aBribe < rec.bribe) {
            if (rec.lchild == null) {
                rec.lchild = this.createRecord(name, aBribe);
            } else {
                Insert(rec.lchild, name, aBribe);
            }
        } else {
            if (rec.rchild == null) {
                rec.rchild = this.createRecord(name, aBribe);
            } else {
                Insert(rec.rchild, name, aBribe);
            }
        }
    }

    public void view() {
        if (root == null) {
            System.out.println("Tree is empty" + "\n");
        } else
            DisplayTree(root);
    }

    public void DisplayTree(PersonRec root) {
        if (root == null)
            return;

        DisplayTree(root.lchild);
        System.out.println(" " + root.name + ":" + root.bribe);
        System.out.println("\n");
        DisplayTree(root.rchild);

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Tree myList = new Tree();
        int choice;

        do {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("\nMenu\n");
            System.out.println("==============================\n\n");
            System.out.println("1. Add student to waiting list\n");
            System.out.println("2. View waiting list\n");
            System.out.println("3. Exit program \n_");
            System.out.println("Please enter choice: ");
            choice = scan.nextInt();

            switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                myList.Add();
                break;

            case 2:
                myList.view();
                break;

            }
        } while (choice != 3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually the real problem is that `root = new PersonRec();` replaces the local variable, it should be `this.root = new PersonRec();`

Comment: Or to be more precise, one of the problems. :)

Comment: If you do this.root = new PersonRec();, you will have only one item in your tree forever.

Comment: Thank you biziclop.  I changed to this.root = new PersonRec() and for the rest of the varialbes and it worked.

Comment: I ran the program and it works, but when I add new names to the tree the previous name and bribe gets replaced by new name.  Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: I put the full code with name added in PersonRec. Did you mean this?